# Returning multiple result sets from server-side procedures in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-11

This [blog post](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-11-server-side-procedures-part-1/) by a Postgres consulting company mentions that the new server-side procedure support in Postgres 11 would be able to return multiple result sets.

➥ Did this feature indeed appear in the Postgres 11 release?

If so, can you explain how it works briefly? Show some code example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did this feature indeed appear in the Postgres 11 release?

No. I think the blog post refers to the ["Dynamic result sets from procedures"](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4580ff7b-d610-eaeb-e06f-4d686896b93b@2ndquadrant.com) patch, which did not make it into the released version.

Answer (score 9):

you can return multiple result sets from a procedure - similar to the way it has always been possible with a function:

```
create procedure getdata(result_one inout refcursor, result_two inout refcursor)
as
$$
begin
  open result_one for 
    select * 
    from (values (1,2,3), (4,5,6)) as t(a,b,c);

  open result_two for 
    select * 
    from (values ('one'),('two'),('three'),('four')) as p(name);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

However, displaying the results is a bit cumbersome - at least in `psql`:

```
postgres@localhost/postgres> \set AUTOCOMMIT off

postgres@localhost/postgres> call getdata(null, null);
     result_one     |     result_two
--------------------+--------------------
 <unnamed portal 1> | <unnamed portal 2>
(1 row)

postgres@localhost/postgres> fetch all "<unnamed portal 1>";
 a | b | c
---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3
 4 | 5 | 6
(2 rows)

postgres@localhost/postgres> fetch all "<unnamed portal 2>";
 name
-------
 one
 two
 three
 four
(4 rows)

postgres@localhost/postgres>
```

Some SQL clients can display the results automatically though.